# How to add Linkedin public posts feed (not my own posts) to my website

Tags: linkedin-api

I cannot find in the API permission to add Linkedin public posts feed (not my own posts) to my website. Is anyone familiar with that?

Comment: I am after the same - not sure it is possible like say Twitter ...